# jsonschema error: Schema "schema-name/properties/hashes" already exists with different definitions

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm using jsonschema to do validation on a json file. The problem is that when I try to run the schema I get the following error:

```
Error:Schema <http://cyclonedx.org/schema/bom-1.3.schema.json#/properties/hashes> already exists with different definition.
```

However if I use an online validator and run the schema it say its valid.

My code looks like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var validator = new Validator();


const sbombJson = process.argv[3];
const testJson = process.argv[4];

const jsonSchemaValitaor =(schema,test) =>{

  console.log(validator.validate(test, schema).errors);

}


const sbombSchema =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(sbombJson,'utf8'));
const test =  JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testJson,'utf8'));

jsonSchemaValitaor(sbombSchema,test);
```

I'm very new to json schemas so my apologies if this is a super easy question but I would
appreciate the help.

schema url: https://cyclonedx.org/schema/bom-1.3.schema.json

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says: you have multiple subschemas with `"$id": "#/properties/hashes"`.  The online validator should be detecting that as an error as well.

FWIW, it is an error in all cases to use fragments (content following "#") in an $id, so the online validator has a bug there too. You should remove all the "$id" tags that start with "#" as they are not valid per the specification, and serve no purpose.

Comment: The given schema is draft-07, so a fragment-only `$id` is valid and is how you define a named anchor. However, the `/` character is not a valid character in an anchor, so those `$id`s are invalid for that reason. It doesn't make sense to define a named anchor that looks like a JSON Pointer anyway, so removing them is definitely the right thing to do.

Comment: This schema is one of those autogenerated ones. This is always the sign.

Comment: @Relequestual I wish we could stop that tool from doing that. json pointer fragments in $ids has never been valid.

Comment: "I wish we could stop that tool from doing that." I created an issue on the repo that has been ignored. Here's the like in case anyone wants to help bug them to get this fixed, https://github.com/jackwootton/json-schema/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have defined `"$id": "#/properties/hashes"` twice.

It looks like you copied that subschema from a JSON Schema which was generated by a tool. The tooling which generates these schemas often adds uneeded (and actually unhelpful) `$id`'s for every property.

Removing those definitions should prevent the error.